# Does Mingw 4.8.2 support ' #pragma once'

Tags: gcc, mingw

I currently have the following mingw

```
gcc --version
gcc (x86_64-win32-seh-rev3, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

My question is does Mingw support `#pragma` keyword and does it support `#pragma once`

Comment: You could have answered this question fairly easily by trying it.

Comment: "yes" to both questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real question is whether gcc (the compiler portion of the MinGW system) supports `#pragma once`.

The answer is yes. The `#pragma` feature is actually supported by the C preprocessor used by gcc, which is documented separately. Gnu CPP's implementation of `#pragma once` is [described here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Alternatives-to-Wrapper-_0023ifndef.html). Depending on how your system is configured, you might be able to read this on your system by typing `info cpp` and search for `#pragma once`.

I do not advise using `#pragma once`, however. It's not specified by the C standard, and so it's not portable to other compilers.  Unless you can guarantee that your code will never need to be compiled by a compiler that doesn't support `#pragma once`, you're probably better off using the conventional `#ifndef` method, known as an "include guard", described in the [previous section of the same manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Once-Only-Headers.html).

Comment: It is supported by GCC, Visual C++, Clang/LLVM, IBM C++ and Intel C++. I don't know any other compilers around here which has no support for #pragma once. Maybe PGI?

Comment: The last I knew, the PGI compiler by The Portland Group did not support `#pragma once`. That is the only one I know of.